# Do triggers before update and after update eliminate race conditions?

Tags: salesforce

I have a invoice object and a payment object. I want to be able to add payments to the invoice until the outstanding amount on the invoice is zero. In no cases should the outstanding amount on the invoice be less than zero.

I can create a update trigger than checks the payment amount that is about to be applied to the invoice, and throw an AddError to prevent the data from committing. But, should I use before update or after update?

Can there be a race condition. If two people commits a payment of 200$ at virtually the same time on an invoice with 200$ outstanding amount. Can the outstanding amount on the invoice be 200$ for both triggers, and therefore both payments are applied to the invoice. This would bring the total in the negative.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the `For Update` keywords in the [Locking Statements](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_locking_statements.htm) docs.

Using this will ensure the transaction completes before another user can update it.